# How to search for parts of text with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have some values in a collection in a document. For example, my key `range` can be:

- `10 - 29`
- `30 - 39`
- `40 - 49`

Those are all strings. I want to somehow search (in MongoDB) for strings starting with `10` and ending with `49`. How can I do this?

I know I should have these as numbers, but that's not possible due to the structure of how the system was created.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, best option would have been to model these as numerals. However, my best (only) alternate suggestion would be to use a regex search.
See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) for the docs on regex search for mongo and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) for creating range expressions.

Depending on possible range, your query would be something like

```
db.collection.find( { range : /[1-4][0-9] - [1-4][0-9]/ } );
```

which matches your range options specified `[10 - 29, 30 - 39, 40 - 49]`. Note this would also match `49 - 10` for example, so you would need to harden that expression up if there are any exclusions not mentioned in the question.

Note regex queries come at a performance cost, remodeling and using built in `$gt $lt` functions would certainly be desirable.

Good luck!

Comment: Make sure to use a rooted regex if possible (i.e., start with `^`), otherwise indexing won't work.

Comment: @mnemosyn Great catch, important point to understand when your indexes are being used.